Nest.js Winston logger not logging to syslog with facility user = 1
I need to change default logger in my Nest.js application because I need to logging to syslog with facility user which has number 1. I need this because Kibana on server is set just for this facility. I wrote new module which seems like this
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WinstonModule } from 'nest-winston';
import * as winston from 'winston';
import { Syslog } from 'winston-syslog';

@Module({
  imports: [
    WinstonModule.forRoot({
      levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        winston.format.printf((info) => {
          return `${info.timestamp} [${info.level.toUpperCase()}] - ${
            info.message
          }`;
        }),
      ),
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new Syslog({
          facility: 'user',
          format: winston.format.combine(
            winston.format.timestamp(),
            winston.format.json(),
          ),
        }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
})
export class LoggerModule {}

I also set added this module to the app.module.ts and set as default logger in main.ts
app.useLogger(app.get(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER));

In my service I injected this as service
@Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER)
private readonly logger: LoggerService,

Localy it's logging fine but in Kibana is 0 logs and server said I am still logging with facility with number 3.
Can someone help me with this please?
